# How to enumerate es6 class methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I enumerate methods of an ES6 class? similar to `Object.keys`

Here's an example:

```
class Callbacks {
  method1() {
  }

  method2() {
  }
}

const callbacks = new Callbacks();

callbacks.enumerateMethods(function(method) {
  // method1, method2 etc.
});
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`Object.keys()` iterates only enumerable properties of the object. And ES6 methods are not. You could use something like [`getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames).  Also methods are defined on prototype of your object so you'd need `Object.getPrototypeOf()` to get them. Working [example](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ic4ga97x/):

```js
for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(callbacks))) {
    let method = callbacks[name];
    // Supposedly you'd like to skip constructor
    if (!(method instanceof Function) || method === Callbacks) continue;
    console.log(method, name);
}
```

Please notice that if you use Symbols as method keys you'd need to use [`getOwnPropertySymbols()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) to iterate over them.

Comment: You also need to do `getOwnPropertySymbols`. Or use `Reflect.ownKeys`

Answer (score 0):

There is no iterator / getter method like `Object.keys` in ES6 (yet?). you can, however, use `for-of` to iterate over the keys:

```
function getKeys(someObject) {
    return (for (key of Object.keys(someObject)) [key, someObject[key]]);
}

for (let [key, value] of getKeys(someObject)) {
    // use key / value here
}
```

Comment: I though it was `for ... in` for keys of properties, and `for ... of` for `foreach` style