# Why are ES6 class methods not showing up in the prototype?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I was wondering if, with the ES6 `class` syntax, the methods are kept in memory once per prototype, or once per instance/object.

To demonstrate my findings, here is a short example:

ES5

```js
function X1(x) {
    this.x = x;
}
X1.prototype.getX = function () {
    return this.x;
};

// X1.prototype = { getX: [Function (anonymous)] }
```

ES6

```js
class X1 {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
}

// X1.prototype = { }
```

Why is the `getX` method not showing up in the prototye?

Comment: Are you maybe getting confused because `getX` is a non-enumerable property? It is on the prototype, but depending on how you are enumerating all of the properties, or may or may not show up.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yep that was actually it, thanks! :)

Comment: [ES6 `class` methods are not enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31423573/1048572), so your console might hide them by default

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the link, got it figured out - was just a little misunderstanding on my part. I'm going through a course right now and got a bit confused with the different concepts and forgot about this right here.

Comment: OP said 'I misunderstood', not 'had a typo'! This can be easily misunderstood! Even using the same Class, defining a method in the class def, it won't show when inspecting, eg. `Object.getPrototypeOf(<Class or Instance of Class>)` but adding a method to it's prototype does, eg. `myClass.prototype.newMethod = ...` (even same class, only the latter would show) - and there's not a lot of clear docs as to why methods don't show up (even when using `util.inspect` in node) only when using something doc'd as 'syntactic sugar' - eg. MDN says class definition is equivalent, yet it acts different!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're mistaken:

```js
class X1 {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
}

console.log(typeof X1.prototype.getX)
console.log(typeof X1.prototype.foo)
```

Comment: Thank you for that short example :)